# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to the forum so if I break some conventions please give me a heads up. 
I'm trying to implement an ANN to solve a PDE, however I get the error message quoted in the title.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
'2.2.0'
```

My functions for sampling the domain and the loss function (that's where the problem seems to lie)

```
# Sampling
def sampler(N1, N2, N3):
    np.random.seed(1)
    # Sampler #1: PDE domain
    t1 = np.random.uniform(low=T0 - 0.5*(T - T0),
                           high=T,
                           size=[N1,1])
    s1 = np.random.uniform(low=S1 - (S2 - S1)*0.5,
                           high=S2 + (S2 - S1)*0.5,
                           size=[N1,1])

    # Sampler #2: boundary condition
    t2 = np.zeros(shape=(1, 1))
    s2 = np.zeros(shape=(1, 1))

    # Sampler #3: initial/terminal condition
    t3 = T * np.ones((N3,1)) #Terminal condition
    s3 = np.random.uniform(low=S1 - (S2 - S1)*0.5,
                           high=S2 + (S2 - S1)*0.5,
                           size=[N3,1])

    return (t1, s1, t2, s2, t3, s3)

# Loss function
def loss(model, t1, x1, t2, x2, t3, x3):
    # Loss term #1: PDE
    V = model(t1, x1)
    V_t = tf.gradients(V, t1)[0]
    V_x = tf.gradients(V, x1)[0]
    V_xx = tf.gradients(V_x, x1)[0]
    f = V_t + r*x1*V_x + 0.5*sigma**2*x1**2*V_xx - r*V 

    L1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(f))

    # Loss term #2: boundary condition
    L2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(V)) 

    # Loss term #3: initial/terminal condition
    L3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model(t3, x3) - x3))

    return (L1, L2, L3)
```

model

```
# Set random seeds
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)


# PDE parameters
r = 0.05            # Interest rate
sigma = 0.25        # Volatility

# Time limits
T0 = 0.0 + 1e-10    # Initial time
T  = 1.0            # Terminal time

# Space limits
S1 = 0.0 + 1e-10    # Low boundary
S2 = 1              # High boundary

#Model specification
num_layers = 3
nodes_per_layer = 6
ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

#Adding the Input and hidden layers
i=0
while i != num_layers:
  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=nodes_per_layer, activation='relu'))
  i += 1

#Adding the output layer
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))

# Training parameters
steps_per_sample = 10
sampling_stages = 800

# Number of samples
NS_1 = 1000
NS_2 = 0
NS_3 = 100


t1, s1, t2, s2, t3, s3 = sampler(NS_1, NS_2, NS_3)
t_total = np.concatenate((t1,t2,t3))
s_total = np.concatenate((s1,s2,s3))

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
t1_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x1_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
t2_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x2_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
t3_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
x3_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

L1_t, L2_t, L3_t = loss(ann, t1_t, x1_t, t2_t, x2_t, t3_t, x3_t)
loss_t = L1_t + L2_t + L3_t
```

The last line is where I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-3acdd7516b24> in <module>()
      7 x3_t = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
      8 
----> 9 L1_t, L2_t, L3_t = loss(ann, t1_t, x1_t, t2_t, x2_t, t3_t, x3_t)
     10 loss_t = L1_t + L2_t + L3_t

3 frames

<ipython-input-4-2ab32c0f7a88> in loss(model, t1, x1, t2, x2, t3, x3)
      5     V_t = tf.gradients(V, t1)[0]
      6     V_x = tf.gradients(V, x1)[0]
----> 7     V_xx = tf.gradients(V_x, x1)[0]
      8     f = V_t + r*x1*V_x + 0.5*sigma**2*x1**2*V_xx - r*V
      9 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in gradients_v2(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
    300         ys, xs, grad_ys, name, True, gate_gradients,
    301         aggregation_method, stop_gradients,
--> 302         unconnected_gradients)
    303   # pylint: enable=protected-access
    304 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients, src_graph)
    534     xs_set = object_identity.ObjectIdentitySet(xs)
    535     grad_ys = _DefaultGradYs(grad_ys, ys, colocate_gradients_with_ops,
--> 536                              gradient_uid)
    537 
    538     # The approach we take here is as follows: Create a list of all ops in the

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py in _DefaultGradYs(grad_ys, ys, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gradient_uid)
    165   new_grad_ys = []
    166   for i, (y, grad_y) in enumerate(zip(ys, grad_ys)):
--> 167     with _maybe_colocate_with(y.op, gradient_uid, colocate_gradients_with_ops):
    168       if grad_y is None:
    169         if y.dtype.is_complex:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: At least one of your elements in `ys` is `None`, so `y.op` will raise that error. Check how you generate that `ys` and make sure it has valid values inside (you'll need to trace what value of the ones you pass to `tf.gradients` becomes `ys` in the line that raises the error, but from `V_xx = tf.gradients(V_x, x1)[0]` it seems it's either `V_x` or `x1`)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! 
Is my reasoning here correct: since `tf.gradients(V, x1)[0]` works the problem must be with `V_x` , right

Comment: It's likely, yes. Can't say for sure, though

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the fact that output from the previous layer was not fed into the subsequent layers. The below code needs to be modified to take inout from previous layers

```py
#Adding the Input and hidden layers

i = 0

while i != num_layers:

  ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=nodes_per_layer, activation='relu'))

  i += 1
```